# Removing 'http://' from link via REGEX

Tags: php, regex

### What I would like to do is remove the "http://" part of these autogenerated links, below is an example of it.

http://google.com/search?gc...

### Here are the regexes I am using in PHP to generate these links from a URL.

```
    $patterns_sp[5] = '~([\S]+)~';                          
    $replaces_sp[5] = '<a href=\1 target="_blank">\1<br/>';

    $patterns_sp[6] = '~(?<=\>)([\S]{1,25})[^\s]+~';        
    $replaces_sp[6] = '\1...</a><br/>';
```

### When these patterns are run on a URL like this:

http://www.google.com/search?gcx=c&ix=c1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=regex

the REGEX gives me:

```
   <a href="http://www.google.com/search?gcx=c&ix=c1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=regex" target="_blank">http://google.com/search?gc...</a>
```

---

### Where I am stuck:

There is no obvious reason why I cannot modify the fourth line of code to read like this:

```
    $patterns_sp[6] = '~(?<=\>http\:\/\/)([\S]{1,25})[^\s]+~';
```

However, the REGEX still seems to capture the "http://" part of the address, thus making a long list of these very redundant looking. What I am left with is the same thing as in the first example.

Comment: please see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454). You need to use an HTML parser, not a regex to deal with HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Replace...

```
$patterns_sp[5] = '~([\S]+)~';
```

...with...

```
$patterns_sp[5] = '~^(?:https?|ftp):([\S]+)~';
```

Then you can access the protocol-less version with `$1` and the whole link with `$0`.

Optionally, you can remove a leading protocol with something like...

```
preg_replace('/^(?:https?|ftp):/', '', $str);
```

Comment: The only way I can think to do this is to create a new pattern. The way I have constructed it maintains the original address, while only modifying it between the <a> and </a>. While what you say would work, it seems like creating another expression could be burdensome.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest **not** writing your own regex, instead have a look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

Retrieve the components of the URL, then compose a new version that only contains the parts you want.